# Google ios sdk - maps work in simulator but not in device - ClientParametersRequest failed with request timed out error

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am running a map based application using google ios sdk. Have created a ios api key and added it to the app. Works well in simulator but not in device. When tried running it in Ipad, the app runs and the markers are added but the underlying map is greyed out.  No map but markers. The console error message is below. Any help appreciated..

```
ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1d5656e0 
{
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x2333dc70 "The request timed out."}
2013-07-12 15:40:23.452 TreeInspect[330:907] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1d5656e0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x2333dc70 "The request timed out."
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the error message "the request timed out", it looks like you just don't have an active Internet connection.